# How do iphone apps know about other apps?

Tags: ios

I recently downloaded an app (Overkill) and they have an in game "virtual currency"  called "overkill medals" or "OM". You can use the in-app purchase system to buy more OM, or you can earn it, through their service called "Tapjoy."

Tapjoy (inside the Overkill app) brings up a menu with eligible apps, and a link to the iTunes store to download it and requires you to "download and open" the app in order to earn your OM.

How does this app know that I have downloaded and opened the app, in order to award me the OM?

**Edit:** It also seems to know when I had the app already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app is likely checking to see if another app has registered a custom URL scheme, by calling `UIApplication canOpenURL`, against a list of known schemes dolled out by Tapjoy to each implementor.

Comment: although this doesn't explain how it knows it is a new installation or an app I already had.

Comment: well, if it checked for the app once and it wasn't installed, then checked again later and it was, it would know the app was a new installation since the previous check.  yes?

Answer (score 2):

The isn't anything within the Apple's iOS SDK that would allow this, so in all likelihood each of these apps is registering with a web service. The server is tracking installation and use of the various apps by relating the unique device id.